# "Operation must be an updateable query" Error

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, mpf

So I keep getting this error message:
[image]

from my function that calls this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE    EQL_DATA1
SET       SubCategoryID = 'value', ItemSize = 'value', Ell = 'value', Tee = 'value', 
          LngEl = 'value', Chk = 'value', Bfy = 'value', Gate = 'value', Alm= 'value',
          DPV = 'value', [45Ell] = 'value', Teerun = 'value', 
          Coup = 'value', Swg = 'value'
WHERE     (SubCategoryID = ?) AND (ItemSize = ?) AND (Ell = ?) AND (Tee = ?)
          AND (LngEl = ?) AND (Chk = ?) AND (Bfy = ?) AND (Gate = ?) AND 
          (Alm = ?) AND (DPV = ?) AND ([45Ell] = ?) AND (Teerun = ?) AND 
          (Coup = ?) AND (Swg = ?)
```

Not sure if my SQL is off, as I'm not 100%, but the idea is to update the contents of my DB with this query.  Even though it is an UPDATE query, it's telling me it's not.

I've been trying to solve this for 2 days and I think I'm just lost in the woods at this point.

C#:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int iPipeType = GetPipeNumber();

        int i = 0;
        try 
        {
            for (;i<lstNewTable.Count; i++)
            {
                daAdapter.UpdateQuery(iPipeType, SizeToSizeID(lstNewTable[i].ItemSize), (decimal)lstNewTable[i].Ell, (decimal)lstNewTable[i].Tee, (decimal)lstNewTable[i].LngEl, (decimal)lstNewTable[i].Chk,
                    (decimal)lstNewTable[i].Bfy, (decimal)lstNewTable[i].Gate, (decimal)lstNewTable[i].Alm, (decimal)lstNewTable[i].DPV, (decimal)lstNewTable[i]._45Ell,
                    (decimal)lstNewTable[i].Teerun, (decimal)lstNewTable[i].Coup, (decimal)lstNewTable[i].Swg);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg.Message + "\n" + msg.GetBaseException().ToString(),"Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation); 
        }

        this.Close();
    }
```

Any constructive help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suspect the SubCategoryID is a key into the table that cannot be updated.  Then the Where should be  : Where SubCategory = '123'.  You don't need every field to be in the WHERE.

Comment: What type is daAdapter? Can we see its construction?

Comment: I assume EQL_DATA1 is a table?

Comment: Correct - EQL_DATA1 is a table

Comment: daAdapter is a generated table adapter that VS created.  The constructor is like 1000 lines.

Comment: I've read some posts and my guess is an issue with the connection string. Do you have by any chance **IMEX=1** in the connection string?

Comment: This `[45Ell] = 'value'` seemed strange.  is that really the name of a column?

Comment: 45Ell is the name of a column in the DB.

Comment: jdweng - if I remove all the other columns, will it still pass the updated values from the lstNewTable[i]?  Sorry if that seems like a dumb question.  I've never done anything like this before...

Comment: Just to confirm - what DB are you connecting to? Can you share connection string?

Comment: It's an access DB, and no I cannot.  Sorry about that.  For what it's worth, I don't think the connection string is the problem.  I have 0 problems retrieving data from the DB.  It's only this UPDATE nonsense that's giving me problems.  If only end-users didn't need this functionality...
  
MSDN is saying that it's because the TEMP file settings are likely set to "Read Only" as opposed to "Read/Write".

Comment: Is the database file readonly?

Comment: It was not set to Read Only